# Upgraded WSO2 from v5.11.0 to v6.2.0- NameID incorrect (never changes)

Tags: upgrade, wso2-identity-server

I have manually entered a new service provider and a new Inbound Authentication Configuration >> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration issuer.  But no matter what I put in the NameID format field the NameID does not change.  I can see this in the decomposed SAML token as well:

--NameID format: **urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent**
saml2:Subject
**<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">52e9f14c-4b7b-47ca-abfc-2d75aa3dcd65</saml2:NameID>**
<saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
<saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2023-06-19T14:18:26.048Z" Recipient="https://***MY-URL***"/>
</saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml2:Subject>

--NameId format: **urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:transient**
saml2:Subject
**<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:transient">52e9f14c-4b7b-47ca-abfc-2d75aa3dcd65</saml2:NameID>**
<saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
<saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2023-06-19T14:21:05.799Z" Recipient="***MY-URL***"/>
</saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml2:Subject>

I was expecting the NameId field to change based on this setting- it almost looks like the NameID value being sent is encrypted instead- though the value never changes.

Did the way the NameID field is handled change in v6.02?  This must be a flag somewhere that I am unaware of

I was expecting the NameID value to change based on the NameID format value- that is not happening at the moment.

Comment: As per the doc, https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf, the value provided with both nameIDFormat is ok. 
Both are unique values for the subject.
what is the different value you expect for these two name ID formats?